# When is it safe to Dispose a nil pointer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

In the following example:

```
program DisposeProblem;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  Person = record
    name: string;
    age: Integer;
  end;

var
  p: ^Person;

begin
  p := nil;
  Dispose(nil); // OK
  Dispose(p); // AV
end.
```

Why is the first `Dispose()` call OK, while the second causes an access violation error? When I step through the code, the first `Dispose()` calls `System._FreeMem()`, while the second calls `System._Dispose()`, but I don't understand why this is the case. I would like to understand this behavior so I can know when it is safe to call `Dispose()` on a `nil` pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to understand this behavior so I can know when it is safe to call `Dispose()` on a `nil` pointer.

It is **never** OK to call `Dispose()` on a `nil` pointer *variable*.  The RTL expects the variable to point at valid memory allocated with `New()`, and so will **unconditionally** try to finalize whatever data/object is being pointed at.  Passing in a pointer variable that is `nil` leads to *undefined behavior* and will likely crash.

`Dispose(nil)` is effectively a no-op. The compiler knows the `nil` literal can't possibly point at a data type that needs to be finalized, so it doesn't need to call `System._Dispose()`, hence it calls `System._FreeMem()` instead (why it calls anything at all, I don't know).

`System._FreeMem()` allows `nil` as input, it will simply exit without doing anything. However, `System._Dispose()` on a pointer *variable* does not allow `nil` as input (and never has).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is it a good practice to have a function like `SafeDispose` that checks for nil first and use that when appropriate? Also, my misconception came from this quote: "Dispose quietly ignores an attempt to free a nil pointer" from [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/delphi-in-a/1565926595/re68.html), which I guess is not a very good source.

Comment: I don't know what Ray Lischner was referring to. Looking at the actual source code for `System._Dispose()` in several versions going back many years, it definitely does not allow `nil` as input.

Comment: No it's not good practise to write a SafeDispose function like that. Why don't you know that your allocation succeeded?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You may have code that is ambiguous in terms of allocating or not...